# How can I add constrainment to javascript dragElement

Tags: javascript, draggable

I have some code for dragging an element that is using vanilla javascript and it works fine but I am scratching my head as to how to constrain it to t, l, r, b or at least top and left. Please no jquery.

```
function dragElement(elmnt) {
  var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
    elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;

  function dragMouseDown(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;

document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
// call a function whenever the cursor moves:
document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
  }

  function elementDrag(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    e.preventDefault();
    // calculate the new cursor position:
    pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
    pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
    pos3 = e.clientX;
    pos4 = e.clientY;

    // if (value = reached / exceeded){ stop dragging any       
    //further please}

elmnt.style.top = (topPos - pos2) + "px";
elmnt.style.left = (leftPos - pos1) + "px";
  }
}
```

I can work out the top (and left) position of the element relative to its parent but can't seem to tell it to stop dragging. I have added a commented example within the code  where I think logically it would be. But so far it means that dragging stops completely rather than 'constrainment', which I am after. Any help appreciated!

Comment: TIP: Calculate the boundaries of the parent and child and make sure the child doesn't exceed them (more than or equal to for T/L, less than or equal to for B/R)

Comment: Calculate the max top / left / bottom / right and use Math.min or max appropriately to ensure you don’t go beyond those limits.

Comment: @bryan60 As mentioned in the post I have those calculations but I do not know how to make it constrain, can you give me an example of min or max as you suggest please?

Comment: @AngelPolitis I have calculated those boundaries - it's the "make sure" part of your comment that I am unsure about.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have calcLeft and calcTop and constraints minLeft, minTop, maxBottom, and maxRight:

```
const left = Math.min(Math.max(minLeft, calcLeft), maxRight)
const top = Math.min(Math.max(minTop, calcTop), maxBottom)
```

then assign those values.

all you're doing is figuring out the max of your calculated position and the minimum position, so you don't go below that, and then the min of that result and your max position, so you don't go above that.

Ensure your maxRight and maxBottom take the size of the element into account.

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a go!